# Self Contained Pinax Project

Tags: django, pinax

I cloned a basic project. I was wondering which files do i have to copy so it becomes a completely self-contained project? I am referring to the css files, the templates, other apps?

Also, where will these files be located.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the layout of the Django project, but these are usually the basic files of a project.

- settings.py
- manage.py
- urls.py

By going into urls.py, you will be able to see their their views are coming from, and those files should also be include. From the views, see what they import, and so on and so fourth until you reach the template files.